# Angular search returning undefined

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ionic-framework

I am making a search page in my app (Angular 14 + Ionic 6) that is searching via API call using GET method and am having some trouble with it. It keeps returning 'undefined' to my console. And there is also the problem with the pipe that after I type some text in the input I get this error in console: `TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'filter')`

Could someone take a look and help me out please? :)

**search.service.ts:**

```
  searchCall(term: string) {
    return from(Preferences.get({key: 'TOKEN_KEY'})).pipe(
      switchMap(token => {
        const headers = new HttpHeaders().set('Authorization', `Bearer ${token.value}`);
        let params = new HttpParams();
        params = params.append('term', term);
        return this.httpClient.get(`${environment.apiUrl}search`, {headers, observe: 'response', params});
      }),
      catchError(err => {
        console.log(err.status);
        if (err.status === 400) {
          console.log(err.error.message);
        }
        if (err.status === 401) {
          this.authService.logout();
          this.router.navigateByUrl('/login', {replaceUrl: true});
        }
        return EMPTY;
      }),
    );
  }
```

**search.page.ts:**

```
export class SearchPage implements OnInit {
  term = '';
  products: any = {
    id: '',
    name: '',
    product_code: '',
  };

  constructor(
    private searchService: SearchService,
  ) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.search(this.term);
  }

  search(term: string) {
    this.searchService.searchCall(term).subscribe(
      (data: any) => {
        console.log('Search: ' + data.body.products);
      },
      error => {
        console.log('Error', error);
      }
    );
  }

}
```

**search.page.html:**

```
<ion-content [fullscreen]="true" class="ion-padding">
  <ion-searchbar [debounce]="1000" placeholder="Search" show-clear-button="focus" [(ngModel)]="term"></ion-searchbar>
  <ion-list>
    <ion-item  *ngFor="let produkt of products?.results | filter : term">
      <ion-label>{{ produkt.product_code }} {{ produkt.name }}</ion-label>
    </ion-item>
  </ion-list>
</ion-content>
```

**filter.pipe.ts:**

```
export class FilterPipe implements PipeTransform {

  public transform(value: any[], filterText: string) {
    return filterText.length > 3 ? value.filter(x => x.name.toLowerCase().includes(filterText.toLowerCase())) : value;
  }

}
```

**EDIT: As requested in comments I am also adding the code from import modules:
My filter pipe is included in the shared.module.ts file and here is the code:**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { FooterComponent } from '../navigation/footer/footer.component';
import { RouterLink } from '@angular/router';
import { IonicModule } from '@ionic/angular';
import { SideMenuComponent } from '../navigation/side-menu/side-menu.component';
import { SafeHtmlPipe } from '../pipes/safe-html.pipe';
import { FilterPipe } from '../pipes/filter.pipe';



@NgModule({
  declarations: [FooterComponent, SideMenuComponent, SafeHtmlPipe, FilterPipe],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    RouterLink,
    IonicModule
  ],
  exports: [FooterComponent, SideMenuComponent, SafeHtmlPipe, FilterPipe]
})
export class SharedModule { }
```

**JSON response from API looks like this:**

```
[
    {
        "id": 3,
        "name": "test",
        "product_code": "45623146546"
    },
]
```

Comment: Are you getting data in `value`? If not, try handling for when it comes as `undefined`, in your filter pipe

Comment: @shrys my http response is 200 success... how can I check if I get data in value?

Comment: you can print it in console just before returning, check in network tab in you dev console or if you're using vscode, put a debugger and attach it to the browser process

Comment: @shrys I have cosnole loged value and it is undefined.... in Network tab the api call is success but the payload is empty... It seems to me  that the search happens before i input any text

Comment: yeah, try handling it before returning it

Comment: or load the component when `products?.results` is fetched (has value) by adding `*ngIf="products?.results"` (second suggestion is only when you don't want to show your component when there's no data)

Comment: @shrys I'm very new to all of this, what dou you mean by "try handling it before returning it"

Comment: in you pipe add a condition `if (value === null || value === undefined) return [];`

Comment: @shrys In my network I am noticing that the term I am searching for is never added to GET request.. how do I trigger the search to send the searched term? My payload is always empty

Comment: i can see `params = params.append('term', term);` where the term is getting added, check your request and your api

Comment: @shrys what exactly should I check for?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/251593/discussion-between-shrys-and-weinde).

Comment: @shrys ok I have whritten you there

Comment: please post your module code.

Comment: @E.Maggini of which module?

Comment: the one related to search component where you likely don't import or export the missing pipe.

Comment: @E.Maggini I am importing filter Pipe like this in shared.module: import { FilterPipe } from '../pipes/filter.pipe';... the shared module is then imported in the search.module.ts file

Comment: Please edit your question to include this information it is not appropriate for comments.

Comment: @E.Maggini there.. updated the question... I hope you can answer it now :

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is mostly likely with how the filter is called, since your updated question shows the pipe itself is imported correctly.

Please try adding a console.log to your pipe like so:

```
export class FilterPipe implements PipeTransform {

  public transform(value: any[], filterText: string) {
    console.log('value', value, 'filterText', filterText);
    return filterText.length > 3 ? value.filter(x => x.name.toLowerCase().includes(filterText.toLowerCase())) : value;
  }

}
```

You will likely see that your expected input of `value` is not an array.

Comment: This is what the console.log shows: value undefined filterText apple.

Comment: Also this error is in the browser console: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'filter')

Comment: Right so this has nothing to do with you pipe and everything to do with your data. `*ngFor="let produkt of products?.results` Post your JSON response that is being used for this.

Comment: Added the JSON response to my question